# Make edit text fit available space Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-edittext

As you can see in the picture the is remaning space to the right of the two buttons, i would like the search bar in the middle to extend as long as it cans, so there is no free space ,should i make those two buttons go to the right and in that way giving more space to the search bar to expand , if so how can i do that to?

[image]

**LAYOUT**

```
  <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/findControls" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:paddingLeft="4dip" android:paddingRight="4dip"
        android:paddingBottom="1dip" android:background="@drawable/topbar">

        <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/ic_btn_find_prev"
            android:id="@+id/find_previous" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/ic_btn_find_next"
            android:id="@+id/find_next" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true" />

        <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_marginRight="6dip">

            <EditText android:id="@+id/find_value" android:layout_width="133dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:singleLine="true" android:ellipsize="end"
                android:inputType="text" android:hint="@string/SearchDialog.Hint" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post the layout you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:background="@color/cardview_light_background">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you very much kind sir

Answer (score 0):

try to use `match_parent` as `layout_width`. And definitly not fixed 133dp.

so for your `LinearLayout` change from `wrap_content` to `match_parent` and add `match_parent` to the `EditText`

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent">

     <EditText android:id="@+id/find_value" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                  android:singleLine="true" android:ellipsize="end"
                  android:inputType="text" android:hint="@string/SearchDialog.Hint" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a RelativeLayout instead:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/findControls"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:paddingBottom="1dip"
          android:paddingLeft="4dip"
          android:paddingRight="4dip"
          android:paddingTop="5dip">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/find_previous"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/find_next"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/find_previous"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add"/>


<EditText
        android:id="@+id/find_value"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:hint=""
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/find_next"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/find_next2"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"/>


<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/find_previous2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/find_next2"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/find_previous2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add"/>
```

Align your Buttons to Parents Left/Right. Set your EditText in between with toLeftOf and toRightOf.